# BibDesk: looking for a keystroke to activate main panel

Tags: macos, bibdesk

Preferring the keyboard for switching between various fields in `BibDesk` (V1.8.15, High Sierra), I am looking for a keystroke to jump back to the main panel.

For example, after searching for a reference in the upper search field I would like to jump directly to the found references. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have Full Keyboard Access enabled in the Keyboard pane of System Preferences, and if there is an item already selected in the main table of a BibDesk window, you can simply press Tab or shift-Tab several times to move keyboard focus forward or backward between search field and main table. If you enter a search term and no item is already selected in the main table, you can press Tab several times until the main table is active, then press the up- or down-arrow key to select an item, or command-A to select all items.

If you don't like pressing Tab so many times, you can also automate the focus-switching with AppleScript. For example, here is an AppleScript that uses UI scripting to activate BibDesk's main table:

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "BibDesk" to set focused of table 1 of scroll area 1 of splitter group 1 of splitter group 1 of window 1 to true
```

To use this AppleScript via a keyboard command:

1. [Enable UI Scripting for BibDesk as described here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/MacAutomationScriptingGuide/AutomatetheUserInterface.html)
2. Open Script Editor on your Mac, paste in the code above, and save it in `~/Library/Application Support/BibDesk/Scripts` so that the script appears as a command (with a name of your choice) in BibDesk's scripts menu
3. [Add an App Keyboard Shortcut for the command as described here](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/create-keyboard-shortcuts-for-apps-mchlp2271/mac)

Comment: @"Big Mac" thx for your answer! Indeed this might be a work around. But I think the exact numbers of Tab you would need depends on your view preferences (in my case I would need 16 Tabs starting from the search field). 

Is there a chance to modify your suggested AppleScript such to activate the main panel directly?

Comment: @Bernd Yes, I am sure there must be a way to activate the main table directly with AppleScript, but I don't know how to do it yet. I will do some more research later and report back if I find a solution. Perhaps someone else knows. You could ask on the [bibdesk-users](https://sourceforge.net/p/bibdesk/mailman/bibdesk-users/) list, where the developer Christiaan often responds, and he is much smarter about these things than I am!

Comment: @Bernd I revised the answer with efficient AppleScript code to switch the focus to the main table in BibDesk.

Comment: @Big_Mac: indeed this script is working ... nice and big thanx